# SwiftUI: disable .refreshable programmatically

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I use a refreshable function available with SwiftUI but I want to disable the function under certain conditions (for example if my list only displays locally saved favorites I don't need to refresh).

I couldn't find anything about it.
Anyone got a solution?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Solution is to not use refreshable isn't it?

Comment: I am using the same list for the global list, sorting unread articles and favorite articles but I only need refreshable for the global list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of this conditional view modifier:

https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/conditional-view-modifier/

You can do this:

```
        .if(condition) { view in
            view.refreshable {
                // do refresh
            }
        }
```

Comment: This will mess up validation of the view hierarchy and SwiftUI will no longer be able to compare view trees between updates, resulting in every update triggering a full reset of the view. For instance, in List views, the list will reset to the top of the screen. Animations will break. Etc.

Comment: @lhunath I don't know where you got your information from, but it works perfectly and I don't have the problems listed

Comment: @dibs if `condition` switches from `true` to `false` while the List is scrolled down, it will fully reset to the top; along with all other effects that result from creating a break in the structural view identity.

Comment: Why would it change while scrolling? the type of list is defined at the start, not during the scroll

Comment: @lhunath Can you can't backup your theory, you are probably making it up based on some wild assumption

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is currently (iOS 17) no perfect solution for this.

The obvious solution works, but has a few disadvantages:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isRefreshEnabled = false

    var body: some View {
        if isRefreshEnabled {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                DemoView()
            }
            .refreshable {
                await loadValue()
            }
        } else {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                DemoView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let's add some debug output using [_printChanges](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10160/) to see what's happening when the `isRefreshEnabled` state changes with this solution:

```
ContentView: _ isRefreshEnabled changed.
<BODY> ContentView
DemoView: @self changed.
<BODY> DemoView
```

As you can see the child `DemoView` does get a re-layout because `@self` has changed. To quote the documentation:

> “@self” is used to mark that the view value itself has changed

In other words, the structural identity of the views involved is changed.

This may cause unwanted side effects like the [onAppear](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onappear(perform:)) method of `DemoView` to be triggered when `isRefreshEnabled` changes.

### Using a View Modifier

You can use a [Conditional View Modifier](https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/conditional-view-modifier/) to prevent some code duplication:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isRefreshEnabled = false

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            DemoView()
        }
        .if(isRefreshEnabled) {
            $0.refreshable {
                await loadValue()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But since this solution using a conditional view modifier is only the short form of the previous code, ***the re-layout behavior remains the same***. I.e. the structural identity of the views involved also changes with this solution.

See [here](https://www.objc.io/blog/2021/08/24/conditional-view-modifiers/) for a detailed explanation of the shortcomings of this approach.

### Workaround

The obvious and simplest solution would be, if the `refreshable` method would accept `nil` as a value not causing a structural identity change of the views.

Unfortunately this is currently not the case, even though the [refresh](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/refresh) environment variable is an optional [RefreshAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/refreshaction). You also can't directly change the environment variable since the setter for the value is not public, i.e. the `refresh` value is not a `WritableKeyPath`.

Furthermore the `RefreshAction` constructor is not public.

After explaining all this, you can use the following solution, but it assumes that `refresh` is a `WritableKeyPath`. At the moment this seems to be the case, but this could change with future iOS versions and may cause the solution to become ineffective.

```swift
struct RefreshableWrapperView<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding var isRefreshEnabled: Bool

    let content: Content
    let refreshAction: @Sendable () async -> Void

    var body: some View {
        RefreshToggling(isRefreshEnabled: $isRefreshEnabled, content: content)
            .refreshable(action: refreshAction)
    }

    init(
        isRefreshEnabled: Binding<Bool>,
        @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content,
        refreshAction: @Sendable @escaping () async -> Void
    ) {
        _isRefreshEnabled = isRefreshEnabled
        self.content = content()
        self.refreshAction = refreshAction
    }
}

private struct RefreshToggling<Content: View>: View {
    @Environment(\.refresh) private var refresh
    @Binding var isRefreshEnabled: Bool

    let content: Content

    var body: some View {
        content
            .environment(EnvironmentValues.safeWritableRefreshKeyPath, isRefreshEnabled ? refresh : nil)
    }
}

private struct RefreshCastFailsafeKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: RefreshAction? = nil
}

private extension EnvironmentValues {
    static let safeWritableRefreshKeyPath: WritableKeyPath<EnvironmentValues, RefreshAction?> = {
        guard let keyPath = \EnvironmentValues.refresh as? WritableKeyPath<EnvironmentValues, RefreshAction?> else {
            return \.refreshFailsafe
        }
        return keyPath
    }()

    var refreshFailsafe: RefreshAction? {
        get { self[RefreshCastFailsafeKey.self] }
        set { self[RefreshCastFailsafeKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

The additional `RefreshToggling` is needed since we cannot create a `RefreshAction` on our own.

You can then use this solution as follows:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isRefreshable = false

    var body: some View {
        RefreshableWrapperView(isRefreshEnabled: $isRefreshable) {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                DemoView()

                Button("Toggle Refreshable") {
                    isRefreshable.toggle()
                }
            }
        } refreshAction: {
            print("Refresh")
        }
    }
}
```

As you will see from the SwiftUI debug output, with this solution the layout process of `DemoView` will no longer be triggered when `isRefreshable` changes.
The reason behind this is that the identity of the `ScrollView` no longer changes due to a state change of `isRefreshable`.